# Db2 connection hangs when query exceeds 1190 characters

Tags: c#, .net-core, db2

I have a dotnet core container app (linux) using the following code to make an async SELECT call to db2 (z/os):

```
            var result = new DataTable();
            var query = "SELECT * FROM DB.TABLE WITH UR;"
            using (var connection = new DB2Connection(_connection))
            {
                await connection.OpenAsync();
                using (var command = new DB2Command(query, connection))
                {
                    using (var myReader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync()) // fails here when query > 1190 chars
                    {
                        result.Columns.AddRange(myReader.GetColumnSchema()
                            .Select(x => new DataColumn(x.ColumnName, x.DataType))
                            .ToArray());
                        result.BeginLoadData();
                        while (await myReader.ReadAsync())
                        {
                            var contents = new object[myReader.FieldCount];
                            myReader.GetValues(contents);
                            result.LoadDataRow(contents, false);
                        }
                        result.EndLoadData();
                    }
                }
            }
```

This code works fine for any query under 1190 characters. When I increase the sql string to 1191 characters or more, the call hangs and times out with the following error:

*IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2Exception (0x80004005): ERROR [08001] [IBM] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected: "170.2.8.84".  Communication function detecting the error: "recv".  Protocol specific error code(s): "110", "*", "*".  SQLSTATE=08001*

The issue does not occur when running with Docker locally. I am unable to run Windows containers on the culprit host, so that comparison is unavailable.

Client:

```
# db2level
DB21085I  This instance or install (instance name, where applicable: "*") uses
"64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL11055" with level identifier "0606010F".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v11.5.5.1", "s2103171200", "DYN2103171200AMD64",
and Fix Pack "1".
Product is installed at "/app/clidriver".
```

A DBA was unable to see any activity for the timed out queries. What could be impeding these calls based on this specific size threshold?

Comment: Troubleshooting needed at your end. Are you running your C# program on linux?  Does the symptom happen if you run the query via `db2cli`?  The "110" code is a timeout, have you defined any non-default values? What's happening on the Db2-server, what is in it's diagnostics?  Get some more experienced eyes on it, but likely only your site can do the troubleshooting

Comment: @mao Yes on Linux. I'm trying your suggestion and attempting the query via `db2cli execsql` but am getting credentials rejected (`SQL30082N Security processing failed with reason "24"`). Troubleshooting that now, will update when I get through. Thanks

Comment: For the life of me I cannot get a command through `db2cli execsql` due to `SQL30082N`. This would be a good test, however I'm moving on from it for now.

Comment: try the suggestion in the answer, to check if the db2cli tool can run for you. You can modify the script to add your specific long query to the inputsql file.  This works for me with a Db2-on-cloud lite plan, from linux, your mileage may vary.

Comment: Additionally, basic eliminations need doing. Does the longer SQL  run correctly when the c# programruns on microsoft-windows, using the same database and same credentials?   Don't forget to edit your question to add facts about the Db2-server platform+`db2level` text output, along with the `db2level` output from your linux client. Lastly, the cli trace facility will show exactly what SQL gets sent from linux to Db2, and that might not be what you assume it to be.

Comment: Looking at `db2trc`... I've been able to use it but there is a learning curve for sifting through results. Have not been able to locate sql statements as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

To test if your db2cli can execute the same SQL statement (i.e. independently of C# and independently of .net core, you can copy and **modify** the script below, by copying the hostname, username, password, and port number from your credentials json file (or wherever you received your connection string details).

If your connection is NOT encrypted with SSL/TLS, modify the script to remove the Security=SSL parameters from the database and dsn definitions below, and use the correct non-SSL port-number.

If your password contains any characters that are considered special by your linux shell, escape each such special character by a backslash \ when assigning the password variable below in the script. Otherwise you will get SQL30082N reason "24".

After you modify this file, chmod +x the file, and run it.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# populate db2dsdriver.cfg for Db2-on-cloud lite and verify db2cli connects and runs SQL statements.
#
# Prereq: (1) an IBM Db2 CLI driver is already installed and on the PATH for current userid.
# Prereq: (2) the version of the CLI driver matches the version of the Db2-lite instance (per the UI dashboard)
# Prereq: (3) after you modify this file, remember to `chmod +x` this file before running it.
#
# This script works with clidriver , with the Db2 runtime client, with the Db2 data server client (fat client).
# Can re-run this script, overwrites current matching entries in db2dsdriver.cfg (if exists) else creates that file.
#
# For IBM Db2-on-cloud (lite plan ,  kostenlos ).
# Configure the db2dsdriver.cfg file for use with db2cli tool to connect to Db2-on-cloud from command-line bash.
#
# You must modify the variable-values below by copying username, password, port, hostname from your credentials json file.
# And remember to escape ( precede with \) any and all special-character in password, otherwise connect will fail.
#
# Note 1: this expects the Db2-on-cloud hostname to have SSL/TLS encrypted-connections to BLUDB which is the default
#   for all IBM Db2-on-cloud hostnames ending with pattern *appdomain.cloud 
#
# Note 2: at clidriver version 11.5.6.0 , db2cli tool can return exit-code 0 even on failure, doh!
#
# Note 3: to get your username and password, host and port-number , download the credentials json file and view it to see them.
#   Then copy their values into the appropriate variables below before making this script executable and run it.
#
set -u

typeset which=/usr/bin/which
typeset db2cli=$( ${which} db2cli )
        [[ -z ${db2cli:=""} ]] && print "\nERROR: please either  dot in a db2profile to allow db2cli to be on the PATH\nor edit your PATH environment variable to put the clidriver/bin directory on the PATH" && exit 1


typeset dbname=bludb   # default database-name for Db2-on-cloud lite plan shared databases.
typeset hostname="change me"
typeset ssl_port_number=32733  # from credentials json
typeset password="change me"  # remember to escape \ any special characters here, copy from credentials json file.
typeset username="change me"  # copy from credentials json file.
typeset dbalias=bludb # you can use whatever alias-name you like, 8 bytes long max
typeset input_sql_tmpfile=/tmp/db2cli_inputsql.sql


${db2cli} writecfg add -database ${dbname} -host ${hostname} -port ${ssl_port_number} -parameter Security=SSL
rc=$?
(( rc > 0 )) && print "\nERROR: failed to write the database to the config file\n" && exit 1

${db2cli} writecfg add -dsn ${dbalias} -database ${dbname} -host ${hostname} -port ${ssl_port_number} -parameter Security=SSL
rc=$?
(( rc > 0 )) && print "\nERROR: failed to write the dsn to the config file\n" && exit 1

${db2cli} validate -dsn ${dbalias} -connect -user ${username} -passwd ${password}
rc=$?
(( rc > 0 )) && print "\nERROR: failed to connect to the dsn with supplied credentials\n" && exit 1


# Verify that the db2cli tool can run some SQL statements by putting them into a file and passing the file to db2cli
#create an inputfile containing SQL statements ( make a temp file for this purpose)
# note that the default statement delimiter for db2cli is crlf (or lf on linux) not semicolon as with db2clp.

echo "values current timestamp" > ${input_sql_tmpfile}
echo "values current server" >> ${input_sql_tmpfile}
echo "values current user" >> ${input_sql_tmpfile}


${db2cli} execsql -execute -dsn ${dbalias} -user ${username} -passwd ${password} -inputsql ${input_sql_tmpfile}
```

Comment: Ah, the special character in the password was the problem. I am able to connect now - sending the large query still results in a timeout. The cursor just hangs after displaying the sql.

Comment: OK, that is an important elimination. It means the problem probably does not lie at the linux end. You  must now pay attention to what is happening at the Db2-server AND the network-path between client and server. You still have not answered the clarification about __which__ Db2-platform (z/os, i series, cloud, linux/unix/windows) the Db2-server runs on,  and also the version/fixpack of the Db2 server, and what is in the Db2-server diagnostics. This is essential information now. Also , you did not respond to the question, if the c# runs OK with this long query from Microsoft-Windows.

Comment: Another simple elimination is to upgrade the clidriver to the present 11.5.6.0 version. If you have a Db2-support contract with IBM they will ask you to do that anyway, in addition to verifying whether the same symptom happens when the c# program runs on microsoft-windows.

Comment: Server is z/os, I need a license to connect. Will look into cli update...I'm just using whatever is offered via IBM's latest nuget for simplicity. I'll also see if I can get more info on server - I was able to meet with a DBA who did not see any threads active for the hung connection.